# Trying to add a class active to my nav bar with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Some one please help me, am trying to add a class active to my navigation items each time I click on one of them. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

html

```
<ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link active">Work</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="about.html" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="mailto:barakadan421@gmail.com" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my css

```
.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and this is my javascript

```
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'),
    navItems = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__item')

for(var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++){
    navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active")
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active", "")
        this.className += "active";
    })
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML too for better responses?

Comment: Are you sure current[0] will exist? Does one element has the active class by default?

Comment: @TusharShahi already added

Comment: The links are already underlined when I check the code in codepen. You will have to remove those first. Is that your problem? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TusharShahi My problem is, when I click on a link to get me on another page, the link clicked should take a new class active with it, to show that is the actual page being navigated,

Comment: https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/MWmWmBq?editors=1111. Is this an accurate repro of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `el.classList.add('.active')`

```
for(var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++){
    navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        // since you are only going to have one element
        // with active class use querySelector() as it
        // will return the first element with this class
        // no need to reference an index
        // provided you already have an active class in your DOM
        var current = document.querySelector(".active")
        // DOM will throw error if there is no active class
        // lets make sure one exists
        if(current){
          // then use classList to add/remove class names
          current.classList.remove('active')
        }
        this.classList.add('active')
    })
}
```

```js
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navItems')

for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
  navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // since you are only going to have one element
    // with active class use querySelector() as it
    // will return the first element with this class
    // no need to reference an index
    // provided you already have an active class in your DOM

    var current = document.querySelector(".active")
    // let s make sure there is a current active class
    // before trying to remove it from DOM
    if (current) {
      // then use classList to add/remove class names
      current.classList.remove('active')
    }
    this.classList.add('active')
  })
}
```

```css
.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navItems active">Home</li>
  <li class="navItems">About</li>
  <li class="navItems">Contact</li>
  <li class="navItems">Projects</li>
  <li class="navItems">Resources</li>
</ul>
```

Refactored using a function that will also make sure an `active` class exists before trying to remove. Also uses `querySelectorAll` to return a ***nodeList*** so we can use ***forEach*** to loop over nodeList. Just a bit cleaner IMHO.

```
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navItems')

// function for use in eventListener passing in event => e
function setActive(e){
  // get the parent of the event the UL
  const parent = e.target.parentNode
  // query the parent and get the active class
  const active = parent.querySelector('.active')
  // check for active class
  if(active){
    // toggle active class
    active.classList.toggle('active')
  }
  // add active class
  e.target.classList.add('active')
}

// forEach loop defining each node as the variable listItem
navItems.forEach(listItem => {
  // running click eventListener on each listItem with our setActive function
  listItem.addEventListener("click", setActive)
})
```

```js
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navItems')

function setActive(e){
  const parent = e.target.parentNode
  const active = parent.querySelector('.active')
  if(active){
    active.classList.toggle('active')
  }
  e.target.classList.add('active')
}

navItems.forEach(listItem => {
  listItem.addEventListener("click", setActive)
})
```

```css
.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navItems active">Home</li>
  <li class="navItems">About</li>
  <li class="navItems">Contact</li>
  <li class="navItems">Projects</li>
  <li class="navItems">Resources</li>
</ul>
```